# How can I render pages in conditional states in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, backend

I have the following code block:

```js
var express = require('express');

var newsRouter = express.Router();

newsRouter.get('/:news_param', (req, res) => {
    let news_params = '/haberler/' + req.params.news_param;

    req.news_list.forEach((news_obj) => {
        if (news_params == news_obj.news_addr) res.render(req.params.news_param);
    });
});

newsRouter.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('news', { news_fetch_from_database: news_list });
})

newsRouter.use((req, res) => {
    res.render('404_page_news');
});

module.exports = newsRouter;
```

`newsRouter.get('/:news_param', ...);` gives the following error when I add `res.redirect('/404');` like this and visit any page different than 404 page:

```
...

newsRouter.get('/:news_param', (req, res) => {
    let news_params = '/haberler/' + req.params.news_param;

    req.news_list.forEach((news_obj) => {
        if (news_params == news_obj.news_addr) res.render(req.params.news_param);
    });

    res.redirect('/404');
...
});
```

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:884:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:922:18)
    at /home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/news.js:12:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

And I need to handle parameters in req.params for rendering pages easily, but I can't solve this issue right now. And I don't want to use filesystem API for security issues.

I simply ran the `npm start` command and visited any valid page, then it gave the following error as I expressed above:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:884:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:922:18)
    at /home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/news.js:12:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/alimkoca/Softwares/szal_web/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: `news_params == news_obj.news_addr` is presumably true for multiple news_obj's so you're trying to respond to the same request multiple times (which isn't possible). You need to decide what you want to do when you get multiple matches (or figure out a way to ensure that you don't get multiple matches).

Comment: *"when I add res.redirect('/404'); within the function"* - The code shown doesn't include that line.  Are you trying to ask about some other, different code?

Comment: Ah yeah, I tried it but it doesn't take place in the code.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I ensure that I don't get multiple matches from any resource.

Comment: @AliKoca: So the error also occurs when you *don't* include `res.redirect('/404');` in the function?  The question seems to indicate otherwise.  Please clarify.  (**Most likely** what's happening here is that you just need to break out of the `forEach()` iteration when you find the record you're looking for, but the information you're providing indicates that you've confirmed this is not the problem, so it's not clear what exactly is happening.)

Comment: @AliKoca — I see no such test in the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is always, unconditionally performing this operation:

```
res.redirect('/404');
```

Which will fail with the error given if the code has already performed this operation:

```
res.render(req.params.news_param);
```

For exactly the reason implied by the error... You can't return a response after you've already returned a response.

It sounds like you want to only *conditionally* return the `404` response.  For example, if no matching record was found:

```
let news_params = '/haberler/' + req.params.news_param;
let record_found = false;

req.news_list.forEach((news_obj) => {
  if (news_params == news_obj.news_addr) {
    res.render(req.params.news_param);
    record_found = true;
  }
});

if (!record_found) {
  res.redirect('/404');
}
```

Or even just `return` from the function when the record is found:

```
let news_params = '/haberler/' + req.params.news_param;

for (let news_obj of req.news_list) {
  if (news_params == news_obj.news_addr) {
    res.render(req.params.news_param);
    return;
  }
}

res.redirect('/404');
```